# Property 'double' does not exist on type 'MyComponent' in vuex-smart-module

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

I have a vue application with typescript. I also use [vuex-smart-module](https://github.com/ktsn/vuex-smart-module).

In my component I get typescript error:

```
Property 'double' does not exist on type 'MyComponent'.
```

In the vuex module I defined a getter:

```
class MyModuleGetters extends Getters<MyModuleState> {
  // You can declare both getter properties or methods
  get double() {
    // Getters instance has 'state' property
    return this.state.count * 2
  }
}
```

And I add the getter by:

```
@Component({
  computed: {
    ...MyModule.mapGetters(['double'])
  }
})
export default class MyComponent extends Vue {
  someFunction() {

    console.log(this.double); // <-- the error is here typescript typo.
```

If I use `Vue.extend({ … })` its solved the problem BUT I need for every component to do `Vue.extend` so basically I create for 2 components each time. which is seems wrong.

Any idea how to make it work without extend?

Comment: Did you tried to rename `double` to something like `myDouble`?

Comment: it is same problem